# How to write AWS Lambda in Java, to consume query string parameters?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

There are many similar threads out there, so I'll try to be simple and specific.

My API Gateway has GET method, without "Use Lambda Proxy integration" check marked. (Yes, to make my life little bit more difficult)

- My assumption is that I have API Gateway portion working correctly, with query string parameters.
- **It has been deployed through Deploy API button**

I also have mapping template written, as exactly said by this [instruction](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pass-api-gateway-rest-api-parameters/) provided by AWS.

Now, in java, I have the following:

```
public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent handleRequest(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event, Context context) {
```

The concern is that `event` object is empty. Have I not been using the correct request event object?

**ADDITIONAL NOTE**

Per request, here's my lambda function below:

```
LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
logger.log("EVENT: " + gson.toJson(event));
```

And here's what CloudWatch prints:

```
EVENT: {}
```

Comment: After making these changes did you deploy your API once again? Your event should have these parameters.

Comment: @NinadGaikwad Thanks for your comment. Yes, it's been deployed, and it is my mystery as well, why my event didn't have these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configured this under GET - > Method Request? [image]

After doublechecking, did you press the deploy button ?
[image]

Comment: Yes, those steps have been followed. Plus, redeployed my lamba code just in case.

Comment: maybe you can provide more details about your lambda?

Comment: Not much to share, but I made a small edit per your request, onto my question section.